# NGXS - Handling of dispatching multiple actions

Tags: angular, ngxs

**Introduction:**

I have an Angular application with NGXS as a state management pattern and Angular Material for the UI components (such as snackbars for notifications).
The application has several different action which I want to dispatch at once when the user clicks the save button. Afterwards I want to inform the user if all actions were successfully dispatched.

**Problem:**

Even if one action fails, I still get the message 'Changes were successfully saved', but the action itself logs the occurred errors. Is there a way to handle errors in the save function differently?

**action 1 - uploadAvatar**

```js
  @Action(UploadAvatar)
  public uploadAvatar(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: UploadAvatar) {
    return this.uploadService.uploadAvatar(ctx.getState().token, action.avatar).pipe(
      tap((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return of(ctx.patchState({ responseStatus: error.status }));
      })
    );
  }
```

**action 1 - updateUser**

```js
  @Action(UpdateUser)
  public updateUser(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: UpdateUser) {
    return this.userService.updateUser(ctx.getState().token, action.user).pipe(
      tap((result: any) => {
        console.log(result);
      }),
      catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
        console.error(error);
        return of(ctx.patchState({ responseStatus: error.status }));
      })
    );
  }
```

**save function**

```js
  public save() {
    try {
      this.store.dispatch(new UploadAvatar(this.avatar));
      this.store.dispatch(new UpdateUser(this.user));
      this.snackbar.showSnackbar('Changes were successfully saved');
    } catch (error) {
      this.snackbar.showSnackbar('Changes could not be saved');
    }
  }
```

Comment: I'm not 100% familiar with ngxs, but maybe you want to handle this by subscribing to `ofActionSuccessful`? => https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/action-handlers

Comment: Alternatively, you can dispatch actions as an array and `subscribe` to their events(ie. completed, error, cancel). See https://www.ngxs.io/advanced/actions-life-cycle

Comment: @Badashi Thanks mate, the links gave me some inspiration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are catching the error in rxjs using `catchError`, so it will never reach your  `try/catch`. Also the dispatch are async, so it will always show the `showSnackbar` with the success message. This might work better.

<sub>Untested code, but maybe you'll understand the idea better</sub>

```typescript
public save(): void {
  this.store.dispatch([
    new UploadAvatar(this.avatar),
    new UpdateUser(this.user)
  ]).subscribe({
    next: () => this.snackbar.showSnackbar('Changes were successfully saved'),
    error: () => this.snackbar.showSnackbar('Changes could not be saved')
  });
}
```

```typescript
@Action(UploadAvatar)
public uploadAvatar(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: UploadAvatar) {
  return this.uploadService.uploadAvatar(ctx.getState().token, action.avatar).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      ctx.patchState({ responseStatus: error.status });

      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}

@Action(UpdateUser)
public updateUser(ctx: StateContext<AuthStateModel>, action: UpdateUser) {
  return this.userService.updateUser(ctx.getState().token, action.user).pipe(
    catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
      ctx.patchState({ responseStatus: error.status });

      return throwError(error);
    })
  );
}
```

Basically, you catch the error in your state, write the response status to the state, and re-throw the same error, which can be caught with the dispatch